# jq: Change multiple values

Tags: jq

I'm trying to change multiple json values with this line

```
 jq '.two="newval", .three="newval"' my.json
```

with this is the input

```
{
  "one": {
    "val": 1
  },
  "two": "val",
  "three": "val",
  "four": "val"
}
```

but the output is 2 jsons:

```
{
  "one": {
    "val": 1
  },
  "two": "newval",
  "three": "val",
  "four": "val"
}
{
  "one": {
    "val": 1
  },
  "two": "val",
  "three": "newval",
  "four": "val"
}
```

How can I change multiple values and output in one item?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a method which uses [+ object addition](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition:+) to update multiple members.

```
. + {two:"newtwo", three:"newthree"}
```

Sample Run (assumes data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M '. + {two:"newtwo", three:"newthree"}' data.json
{
  "one": {
    "val": 1
  },
  "two": "newtwo",
  "three": "newthree",
  "four": "val"
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/X5MI2D4YrH)

Answer (score 66):

Simply change the comma to a pipe character and you’re done:

```
.two="newval" | .three="newval"
```

"," is for concatenating streams: `A,B` will emit A followed by B.

Comment: This syntax is clean and easy to remember than the selected answer.

Comment: this prints the original stream twice for me

Answer (score 3):

This old question is popular on Google and I had a similar need that led to a more concise solution (which I'm not sure if existed at the time of ask). In my case, I needed to assign the same value to multiple keys which fits the example OP gave but it bears warning that this won't work for assigning different values.

##### Solving OP's problem

Keep the comma operator and pass the combined stream to the assignment:

```shell
$ jq '(.two, .three) = "newval"' data.json
```

```json
{
  "one": {
    "val": 1
  },
  "two": "newval",
  "three": "newval",
  "four": "val"
}
```

jqPlay example: https://jqplay.org/s/Jx7m-pnl_OQ

##### My extended problem

---

I needed to mask sensitive (secret) values in Kubernetes manifests that looked like this:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Secret",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "test"
  },
  "data": {
    "foo": "czAwcGVyczNrcml0Cg=="
  },
  "stringData": {
    "baz": "s00pers3krit"
  }
}
```

With a few additional complicating factors:

1. The `foo` and `baz` sub-keys were arbitrary and unknown ahead of time
2. One or both of the `data` and `stringData` keys could be present
3. There may be multiple documents in the input stream and only `.kind == "Secret"` should be masked

##### My solution

---

```shell
$ helm template helm/ | yq '( select(.kind == "Secret")  | (.data[]?, .stringData[]?) ) = "[Masked]"'
```

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Secret",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "secret1"
  },
  "type": "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson",
  "data": {
    ".dockerconfigjson": "[Masked]"
  },
  "stringData": {
    ".dockerconfigjson": "[Masked]"
  }
}
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Secret",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "secret2"
  },
  "type": "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson",
  "data": {
    "baz": "[Masked]"
  },
  "stringData": {
    "quux`": "[Masked]"
  }
}
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "configmap1"
  },
  "type": "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson",
  "data": {
    "foo": "czAwcGVyczNrcml0Cg==",
    "snuffle": "fuzzy"
  }
}
```

1. Use a subselect to assign the static value `[Masked]` to the selected keys:

   ```
   () = "[Masked]"
   ```
2. Select only `.kind == "Secret"` for reassignment:

   ```
   ( select(.kind == "Secret") ) = "[Masked]"
   ```
3. Pipe the selected objects in a stream generator to produce multiple fields to be assigned:

   ```
   ( select(.kind == "Secret") | (., .) ) = "[Masked]"
   ```
4. But only the `data` and `stringData` of those objects:

   ```
   ( select(.kind == "Secret") | (.data, .stringData) ) = "[Masked]"
   ```
5. And really only the subkeys of those (keep `.data` but modify all its child key):

   ```
   ( select(.kind == "Secret") | (.data[], .stringData[]) ) = "[Masked]"
   ```
6. And finally only if those sub keys actually exist:

   ```
   ( select(.kind == "Secret") | (.data[]?, .stringData[]?) ) = "[Masked]"
   ```

jqPlay: https://jqplay.org/s/8SqKgeP1BzN